# Why is this random letter 'y' here?

Tags: floats

I'm making a document for a class, and I've encounter an odd problem. The document has a mysterious letter 'y' in the top right that I can't figure out where it came from or how to get rid of it. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

\begin{huge}
    {\centering
    Gnuplot and \LaTeX\ \footnote[1]{Document author: James Andrews}\par
    }
\end{huge}

\bigskip

Gnuplot is a versatile freeware plotting program. it is available for most platforms. To get Gnuplot see

\noindent http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/gmu/gnuplot\_info.html.

To make the plot below, I used a size setting of '0.7,0.7'. Note the arrow from \textbf{P} at $(\sin(0), \cos(0),0)$ to the point \textbf{Q} at $(\sin(10*\pi),\cos(10*\pi),10*\pi)$. Also note the numbered axis and the title. They were all created by Gnuplot.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics{project4.eps}
\caption{This graph was created with Gnuplot using the 'postscript eps' terminal setting}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and here is the document that it generates:

[image]

As you can see, there is a letter 'y' in the top right. I know it his something to do with my figure because it's not there when I remove that. What is happening here?

Comment: Remove the file extension `.eps` from the image being included as well as the `dvips` driver option from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). Are you compiling with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: I'm using TexStudio's built in compiler.

Comment: And removing those two things gives me this warning: No graphics package `graphic{s,x}' loaded. And doesn't include the image. But oddly, the only time it includes the image is when using the "build and View" option.

Comment: Don't remove `graphicx`, just the added option. Also, if you're using `epstopdf` and wanting to include an EPS in a PDF document, you need to have `--shell-escape` enabled.

Comment: Load `graphicx` before `epstopdf` and use `--shell-escape` as told by Werner. I mean → `\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}`

Comment: unrelated to `y`  but don't use `[h!]` (usually this generates a warning that it is being changed) use `[htp]` or some other option that gives latex more of a chance to position the float (`[h]` means not top, not bottom, not no float page; which is a hard constraint to meet). You do not need `{..}` around `\centering` as `huge` already groups the command

Comment: @Harish Kumar : In the case of recent TeX Live, `--shell-escape`
is not necessary since `repstopdf` is allowed as a
restricted-shell-escape command.

Comment: The y seems to be sans serif like the font of your picture. So perhaps it is simply really in your picture (but outside the bounding box). You could try to clip: `\includegraphics[trim= 0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt,clip]{....}`